# How to refresh the account detail page from publisher action vf page

Tags: apex

**my requirement is a record have feed and detail page.......right.. when i do an update in the feed nothing but publisher action, i need to refresh the detail page related to that**

---

I have a vf page in the publisher action. in that vf page i have one update button.my requirement is that when i click on the update button, the account detail page should refresh. which is not happening.
i have tried in following ways.but of no use.

```
function testRefreshPrimaryTabById() {
            //Get the value for 'scc-pt-0' from the openPrimaryTab method
            var primaryTabId = 'scc-pt-0';
            sforce.console.getFocusedPrimaryTabId(showTabId);
            //sforce.console.getEnclosingTabId(testRefreshPrimaryTabById);
            //window.top.location = "/";
            //window.location.href = 'url';
            sforce.console.top.location.href = 'url';

        }
       var showTabId = function showTabId(result) 
    {  
        var tabId = result.id;
        sforce.console.refreshPrimaryTabById(tabId , true, refreshSuccess);    
    };

    var refreshSuccess = function refreshSuccess(result) 
    {
        //Report whether refreshing the primary tab was successful
        if (result.success == true) 
        {
            alert('Primary tab refreshed successfully');
        } 
        else 
        {
            alert('Primary did not refresh');
        }
    };
  </script>
```

whole console is refreshing which should not be.
only one tab in which i am doing the update should refresh....so that detail page also refreshes.

any suggestions???

Comment: `sforce.console.top.location.href = 'url';` instead try `top.location.href = 'url';`

Comment: if i do like that whole console is refreshing and directed to out of console window.....which should not

Comment: Dileep you need to refresh only current tab correct?

Comment: current tab is already refreshing.....

Comment: my requirement is a record have feed and detail page.......right.. when i do an update in the feed nothing but publisher action, i need to refresh the detail page related to that

Comment: any suggestions ratan???

Answer (score 0):

I have this same requirement.  I'm using a Feed page layout in the Console.  My VF Action is a Button that sets the Case.OwnerId to the current user.  After it's pressed, I need the tab to refresh so the record update shows.  Were you able to get this to work?